# Ubuntu 22.04 how making rAlt + [hjkl] arrows keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap

I have done this before on kubuntu but when I try to do this with xmodmap on ubuntu 22.04, the binds don't work. This is what I was using:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Mode_switch" 
xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H Left H" 
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J Down J"
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K Up K" 
xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L Right L"
```

Does anyone know how what the problem is and how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: xmodmap won't work, since you're in a wayland session. You can change to X-server on your login page (hit the "cogg" icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 uses Wayland by default, which doesn't support xmodmap. The recommended way would be to write your script using XKB instead, since xmodmap is deprecated, but XKB is considerably more complicated.

The easy alternative is to simply use a Xorg session instead of Wayland. To do that, log out of your account, then click the cog icon in the bottom right corner and select "Ubuntu on Xorg". Your sessions will default to Xorg after this and your xmodmap script should start working again.

**Edit:**

Your script works, but I'd just like to point out that you don't really need to change the function of the AltGr key. The following would also work:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H h H Left Left"
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J j J Down Down"
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K k K Up Up" 
xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L l L Right Right"
```

Comment: @vanadium Actually, I think their script is fine. I tested here and it works as intended.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!